# jQuery Ajax data show double using append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm displaying data to `marquee` using jQuery ajax.

When the ajax load (every 1 second), the data always show double.

[image]

Code:

```
var messageLen = jsonStr.message.length;

for(var i=0; i<messageLen; i++)
{
    var message = jsonStr.message[i];

    var newOption = $('<li>'+message+'</li>');
    $('#list').append(newOption);
}
```

HTML

```
<marquee>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
</marquee>
```

So, what I want the data show not double.

*I'm using `$('#list').html(newOption);` it only show 1 data (actual I have more data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty the list before loop

```
var messageLen = jsonStr.message.length;
$('#list').empty();
for(var i=0; i<messageLen; i++)
{
    var message = jsonStr.message[i];

    var newOption = $('<li>'+message+'</li>');
    $('#list').append(newOption);
}
```